# Laravel CLI cUrl Error on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: command-line, nginx, curl

I have already installed the nginx, MySQL, HHVM and Composer, everything is working, so I installed the Laravel CLI to run `laravel new blog` from the terminal but when I run it i get this error:

```
eduardo@eduardo-desktop:~/www$ laravel new blog
Crafting application...

  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]                                      
  cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 29996 milliseconds with 2800182 ou  
  t of 7820187 bytes received                                                  

  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException]                                 
  cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 29996 milliseconds with 2800182 ou  
  t of 7820187 bytes received                                                  

new <name>
```

Someone may help me?

Thank you in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase `default_socket_timeout` in your PHP config file (`~/php.ini`), e.g.

```
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

or set it using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in your PHP code like:

```
curl_setopt($res, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
```